# Fetching documents with calendarItems.minNights first value greater than 2 using Elasticsearch DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-painless

I would like to learn how to fetch documents with the first value of the calendarItems.minNights field greater than 2 using Elasticsearch DSL. The data structure looks like this:

In the above data structure, I want to retrieve documents where the first value of calendarItems.minNights is greater than 2. What should be the Elasticsearch DSL query for this?

Thank you.

Data

```
{
  "_index": "list",
  "_id": "5150",
  "_version": 1,
  "_seq_no": 0,
  "_primary_term": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "id": 5150,
    "title": "test title",
    "calendarItems": [
      {
        "actualDate": "2023-07-10T00:00:00+03:00",
        "price": 458,
        "minNights": 4,
        "status": "booked",
        "reason": null,
        "isBlock": null
      },
      {
        "actualDate": "2023-07-11T00:00:00+03:00",
        "price": 458,
        "minNights": 2,
        "status": "available",
        "reason": null,
        "isBlock": null
      },
      {
        "actualDate": "2023-07-12T00:00:00+03:00",
        "price": 458,
        "minNights": 2,
        "status": "available",
        "reason": null,
        "isBlock": null
      },
      {
        "actualDate": "2023-07-12T00:00:00+03:00",
        "price": 458,
        "minNights": 2,
        "status": "booked",
        "reason": null,
        "isBlock": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Query

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "calendarItems",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "calendarItems.actualDate": {
                                                "gte": "2023-07-07T00:00:00+03:00",
                                                "lte": "2023-07-12T23:59:59+03:00"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "calendarItems.status": "available"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "script": {
                                            "script": {
                                                "source": "2 >= doc['calendarItems.minNights'].value",
                                                "lang": "painless"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "calendarItems",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "calendarItems.status": "booked"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "calendarItems.actualDate": {
                                                "gte": "2023-07-07T00:00:00+03:00",
                                                "lte": "2023-07-12T23:59:59+03:00"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "calendarItems",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "range": {
                                        "calendarItems.actualDate": {
                                            "gte": "2023-07-07T00:00:00+03:00",
                                            "lte": "2023-07-15T23:59:59+03:00"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "calendarItems.status": "available"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "calendarItems",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "range": {
                                        "calendarItems.actualDate": {
                                            "gte": "2023-07-07T00:00:00+03:00",
                                            "lte": "2023-07-07T23:59:59+03:00"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "calendarItems.status": "available"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "script": {
                                        "script": {
                                            "source": "8 >= doc['calendarItems.minNights'].value",
                                            "lang": "painless"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "must_not": [
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "calendarItems",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "calendarItems.status": "booked"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "range": {
                                        "calendarItems.actualDate": {
                                            "gte": "2023-07-07T00:00:00+03:00",
                                            "lte": "2023-07-15T23:59:59+03:00"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}